# Discord bot does not run on Heroku with Python

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I read almost everything on stackoverflow and didn’t understand what my mistake was.

If I run this code myself, then everything goes fine, but on heroku doesnt

```
__author__ = "Switchback|github.com/AidarSource"

import discord
import random
from motivation_phrases import motivations

bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!мотивация'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(motivations))

bot.run(str(token))
```

Procfile, requirements.py, runtime.txt - https://github.com/AidarSource/MotivationDiscordBot

Comment: Lock your requirements.txt properly with: `python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`. You are accessing a variable (`token`) that does not exist. You might be trying not to commit your actual token which is commendable but there is no logic for e.g. extracting a token from environment variable. Without a token your bot cannot run.

Comment: i saved token at heroku config vars. So if i lock the requirements.txt i need to change `discord` to `discord.py==1.3.3`?
Locking requirements.txt does not help me ;(

Comment: There is no logic in your python code from converting the token saved in the environment variables to your python script. E.g. `import os; token = os.environ["TOKEN"]` would retrieve the value of the env var `TOKEN` and save it in the python variable `token`

Comment: nice! thank you bro, you help me! im really grateful